# erlang mysql result to xml

Tags: mysql, xml, erlang, xmpp

I have an output :

```
MysqlResult = {selected,["id","first_name","last_name"],
         [{1,"Matt","Williamson"},
         {2,"Matt","Williamson2"}]}
```

how to make it look like :

```
XML = "
 <result id='1'>
 <first_name>Matt</first_name>
 <last_name>Williamson</last_name>
 </result>
 <result id='2'>
 <first_name>Matt</first_name>
 <last_name>Williamson2</last_name>
 </result>"
```

I am looking for a smart way for placing it into IQ ( ejabberd )

```
IQ#iq{type = result, sub_el =
                   [{xmlelement, "result",
                   [{"xmlns", ?NS_NAMES}],
                   [{xmlelement, "userinfo", [],
                   [{xmlcdata,"???"??  }]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`xmerl`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html) to create XML in Erlang:

```
1> MysqlResult = {selected,["id","first_name","last_name"],
1>          [{1,"Matt","Williamson"},
1>          {2,"Matt","Williamson2"}]}.
{selected,["id","first_name","last_name"],
          [{1,"Matt","Williamson"},{2,"Matt","Williamson2"}]}

2> {selected, _Columns, Results} = MysqlResult.
{selected,["id","first_name","last_name"],
          [{1,"Matt","Williamson"},{2,"Matt","Williamson2"}]}

3> Content = [{result, [{id, Id}], [{first_name, [First]}, {last_name, [Last]}]} || {Id, First, Last} <- Results].
[{result,[{id,1}],
         [{first_name,["Matt"]},{last_name,["Williamson"]}]},
 {result,[{id,2}],
         [{first_name,["Matt"]},{last_name,["Williamson2"]}]}]

4> xmerl:export_simple(, xmerl_xml).
["<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>",
 [[["<","result",[[" ","id","=\"","1","\""]],">"],
   [[["<","first_name",">"],["Matt"],["</","first_name",">"]],
    [["<","last_name",">"],
     ["Williamson"],
     ["</","last_name",">"]]],
   ["</","result",">"]],
  [["<","result",[[" ","id","=\"","2","\""]],">"],
  [[["<","first_name",">"],["Matt"],["</","first_name",">"]],
    [["<","last_name",">"],
     ["Williamson2"],
     ["</","last_name",">"]]],
   ["</","result",">"]]]]

5> io:format("~s", [v(-1)]).
<?xml version="1.0"?><result id="1"><first_name>Matt</first_name><last_name>Williamson</last_name></result><result id="2"><first_name>Matt</first_name><last_name>Williamson2</last_name></result>ok
```

Comment: Yes that's a way. I tried `lists:flatten(xmerl:export_simple([MysqlResult], xmerl_xml)).` but it does not like mysql output.

Comment: You need to convert it to a format `xmerl:export_simple/2` likes (see the documentation). I've added an example. Essentially you create simple XML like structures in Erlang, before exporting.

Answer (score 4):

First extract the results element from the tuple:

```
{selected, _Columns, Results} = MysqlResult.
```

Then convert it to ejabberd's internal XML format with a list comprehension:

```
XML = [{xmlelement, "result", [{"id", integer_to_list(Id)}],
        [{xmlelement, "first_name", [], [{xmlcdata, FirstName}]},
         {xmlelement, "last_name", [], [{xmlcdata, LastName}]}]}
       || {Id, FirstName, LastName} <- Results].
```

And insert it into your IQ record:

```
IQ#iq{type = result, sub_el =
                   [{xmlelement, "result",
                   [{"xmlns", ?NS_NAMES}],
                   [{xmlelement, "userinfo", [],
                   XML}]}]}
```

(assuming that you want the `<result/>` elements as children of the `<userinfo/>` element)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use --xml and --execute option in mysql command line client.

[mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html)

Comment: query is generated in erlang - and comes back to erlang - using external mysql client is not solution. Even I do not need XML varible really - I want to place MysqlResult to IQ . so look like two things I am missing - 1. MysqlResult manipulation , 2. IQ  xml format

Answer (score 0):

The xmerl solution is absolutely fine, and probably the way to go if this is a one-off type thing.

However, if you are writing an xmpp client, even a simple one, consider using exmpp - https://github.com/processone/exmpp . You can use some of the tactics to extract data and generate XML, but in general, the helper functions (most likely within the exmpp_iq and exmpp_stanza modules) will be very handy.

exmpp isn't going anywhere either -- the alpha of ejabberd3 is using it internally (finally)