# How to convert a list of tuples into XML format using xmerl (erlang)

Tags: mysql, xml, erlang

I started to learn erlang but I'm struggling with data type conversions in erlang.

I have a response from mysql:

```
[{message,[{id,"500"}],
    [{from_user,"admin@domain"}],
    [{to_user,"test@domain"}],
    [{txt,"Text message from admin to user"}],
    [{created_at,"2015-08-28 17:48:41"}]},
    ...
 {message,[{id,"550"}],
    [{from_user,"test@domain"}],
    [{to_user,"admin@domain"}],
    [{txt,"message from test to admin"}],
    [{created_at,"2015-08-28 17:48:42"}]}]
```

But I need to return a XML (application/xml):

```
<chat>
  <message>
    <field name="id">500</field>
    <field name="from_user">admin@domain</field>
    <field name="to_user">test@domain</field>
    <field name="txt">Text message from admin to user</field>
    <field name="created_at">2015-08-28 17:48:41</field>
  </message>
  ...
  <message>
    <field name="id">550</field>
    <field name="from_user">test@domain</field>
    <field name="to_user">admin@domain</field>
    <field name="txt">message from test to admin</field>
    <field name="created_at">2015-08-28 17:48:42</field>
  </message>
</chat>
```

I've followed the response for this question, but it didn't work: [erlang mysql result to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484156/erlang-mysql-result-to-xml)
. I didn't get the part: io:format("~s", [v(-1)])

and I tried to code following this example: [Generating XML in Erlang using xmerl](http://userprimary.net/posts/2011/02/16/Generating-XML-in-Erlang-Using-xmerl/)

Assuming the response was:

```
Fields = [[<<"44">>,<<"admin@domain">>, <<"test@domain">>,<<"message here">>, <<"2015-09-08 10:49:26">>],
         [<<"47">>,<<"test@domain">>, <<"admin@domain">>,<<"response to message">>, <<"2015-09-08 10:49:36">>]].
```

What I've tried in my module:

```
-define(xml_prolog, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>").
...

make_xml(Fields) ->
  Xml = xmerl:export_simple([xml_simple(Fields)],
                             xmerl_xml,
                             [{prolog, ?xml_prolog}]),
  unicode:characters_to_binary(Xml).

xml_simple(Fields) ->
  {chat, [{message, lists:map(
    fun(Entry) ->
      conversion(Entry)
    end, Fields)}]}.

conversion(List_of_lists) ->
  Tmp = lists:map(
    fun(E) ->
      entries_to_tuple_of_lists(E)
    end, List_of_lists),
  [ {field, [{id, Id}],
            [{from_user, From}],
            [{to_user, To}],
            [{txt, Body}],
            [{created_at, Date}]} || {Id,From,To,Body,Date} <- Tmp].

entries_to_tuple_of_lists(Entries) ->
  list_to_tuple(
    lists:map(
      fun(Elem) ->
          bitstring_to_list(Elem)
      end, Entries)).
```

Comment: The `v(-1)` refers to the result of the previous command in the Erlang shell, does that help? Either way, it would be best if you showed what you tried and what errors you got as a result, otherwise anyone who answers is left basically repeating the advice already given in what you've linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier to change functions from the example for your data. The result:

```
-module(testxml).

-export([makeXml/1]).

-define(xml_prolog, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>").

fields_to_xml_simple2(Fields) ->
  [
    fun(X) -> [{K, V}] = element(X, Fields), {field, [{name, atom_to_list(K)}], [V]} end(E)
    || E <- lists:seq(2, tuple_size(Fields))].

doc_xml_simple2(Fields) ->
  {chat, [{message, fields_to_xml_simple2(K)} || K <- Fields]}.

makeXml(Fields) ->
  Xml = xmerl:export_simple([doc_xml_simple2(Fields)], xmerl_xml,
    [{prolog, ?xml_prolog}]),
  unicode:characters_to_binary(Xml).
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way but it worked:

The functions:

```
entries_to_tuple_lists(Entries) ->
  list_to_tuple(
    lists:map(
      fun(Elem) ->
        bitstring_to_list(Elem)
      end, Entries)).

element_to_tuple_list(Fields) ->
  Tmp = lists:map(
    fun(E) ->
      entries_to_tuple_lists(E)
    end, Fields),
  [{message,[{id, Id}],
            [{from_user,[From]},
             {to_user,[To]},
             {txt,[Body]},
             {created_at,[Date]}]} || {Id,From,To,Body,Date} <- Tmp].

chat_to_xml(Messages) ->
  {chat, element_to_tuple_list(Messages)}.

make_xml(SqlReturn) ->
  Xml = xmerl:export_simple([chat_to_xml(SqlReturn)],
    xmerl_xml,
    [{prolog, ?xml_prolog}]),
  unicode:characters_to_binary(Xml).
```

And the XML obtained:

```
<chat>
  <message id="500">
    <from_user>admin@domain</from_user>
    <to_user>test@domain</to_user>
    <txt>Text message from admin to user</txt>
    <created_at>2015-08-28 17:48:41</created_at>
  </message>
  ...
  <message id="550">
    <from_user>test@domain</from_user>
    <to_user>admin@domain</to_user>
    <txt>message from test to admin</txt>
    <created_at>2015-08-28 17:48:42</created_at>
  </message>
</chat>
```